# 2D interpolation with interp2

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I want to describe surface flatness of a plane with interp2 function.

Spatial sampling points are as below.

```
width=[0 500];
length=[0 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000];
```

and flatness are as below, at width 0 and 500, respectively.

```
 a = [1 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2 0 -0.2 -0.4 -0.6 -0.8 -1]; % flatness at width 0
 b = [-1 -0.8 -0.6 -0.4 -0.2 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1]; % flatness at width 500
```

With these values, the surface shape will be like following figure.

[image]

I wanted to change this figure into following figure with interp2 function.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
widthq=[0 100 200 300 400 500];

flatness=[a' b'];

flatnessq=interp2(width,length,flatness,widthq,length);
```

But, not working with one error, 'The input data has inconsistent size.'

Can anyone explain this error and give a way how to interpolate my data with interp2 function?

Comment: You transpose `a` and `b` but not `length`. Try keep your dimensions consistent?

Comment: Don't use `length` as a variable name!

Comment: What you have accepted as the answer is not the correct answer - the correct answer is found in @Dan's comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three inputs need all to be of the same size

```
[W, L] = meshgrid(width, length);
```

The last two arguments need also to be of same size

```
[Wq, Lq] = meshgrid(widthq, length);
```

Then it should work

```
flatnessq=interp2(W,L,flatness,Wq,Lq);
```